# ¿Consulta para dividir datos por la fecha?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql, mysql-workbench

tengo el problema que no he podido  realizar una consulta para que dado el  campo fecha_creación type(date)  necesito que se vean todos los datos de mi  tabla me muestre los datos que necesito, lo solicitado seria que si  se repite el mes y el año en que fue guardado muestre el  actual o el que recientemente aya subido, pero de la misma forma que muestre los datos del mes y año.  osea que si  tengo muchas fechas con 2019-02-19 y otras con 2019-01-19. estoy trabajando con workbeanch ejemplo:

fecha_creación type(date)
2019-02-19
2019-01-19
2019-01-19
2019-02-19
2019-02-19

debería de quedar de esta forma
2019-02-19
2019-01-19

que son las ultimas fechas subidas según el  mes que le corresponde.

Esta es la tabla que tengo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes agrupar por esa columna, poniendo algo como `GROUP BY fecha_creacion` Puedes leer [este artículo](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx) y ver algunos ejemplos. Cuidado, mysql es muy permisivo con `GROUP BY` y no alerta cuando escribes consultas poco optimizadas usándolo.

Comment: No creo que me funcione el group by ya que necesito que se muestren todos los campos.

Comment: He leído varias veces tu pregunta y no me queda claro lo que quieres conseguir. Por favor, lee [ask] y luego edita tu pregunta para mejorar su redacción. También sugiero que incluyas, en la muestra de los datos, los valores de las otras columnas que quieres que aparezcan. Finalmente, que no publiques código en imágenes. Incluye directamente el SQL como parte de la pregunta. Un saludo.

Comment: @emmanuelgomeztoledo Podrías poner el código que estas utilizando?

Comment: @c47 a que codigo te refieres ??

Comment: @emmanuelgomeztoledo me parece que no podía ver la imagen que adjuntaste, ahora ya la veo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `group by` te podría funcionar, aunque también puedes aplicar un `DISTINCT` a la consulta para que te muestre los datos filtrados y finalmente usas un `ORDER BY` para organizar las fechas de menor a mayor.